# Mimicking named arguments, a good idea? (programming style)

Tags: programming, coding-style

With respect to code readability I like the possibility to use [keyword (named) arguments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_parameter).

I would like to have this under Mathematica, but AFAIK there is no native support for that.

By example, to define an [inverse gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-gamma_distribution), I come with this approach:

```
createInverseGamma[Mean->m_,Variance->v_]:=
  With[{a=(m^2+2v)/v,b=m (m^2+v)/v},InverseGammaDistribution[a,b]];

createInverseGamma[Mean->m_,StandardDeviation->std_]:=
  createInverseGamma[Mean->m,Variance->std^2];

dist=createInverseGamma[Mean->1,StandardDeviation->2]

Mean[dist]             (* 1 *)
Variance[dist]         (* 4 *)
```

**My question:** do you see some drawbacks to this approach or do you have a better solution?

nb:

- clearly some symbols have to be reserved and protected (here I use Mean, Variance etc... that are already defined).
- this approach can interfere with **Option**, maybe it would be better to define something like `foo[Mean=5]` with "=" instead of ->

---

**update:**

here is an example with "=" instead of ->

```
SetAttributes[createInverseGamma,HoldAll];

createInverseGamma[Mean=m_,Variance=v_]:=
  With[{a=(m^2+2v)/v,b=m (m^2+v)/v},InverseGammaDistribution[a,b]];

createInverseGamma[Mean=m_,StandardDeviation=std_]:=
  createInverseGamma[Mean=m,Variance=std^2];

dist=createInverseGamma[Mean=1,StandardDeviation=2]

Mean[dist]             (* 1 *)
Variance[dist]         (* 4 *)
```

However I am even less sure that it has no deleterious side effect...?

Comment: "[...]  it is usually possible to provide the values in any arbitrary order, [...]" - that's not the case here, right? You could use `KeyValuePattern[{Mean -> m_, ...}]` instead but I find `KeyValuePattern` quite code-obscuring. The call would have to have a single argument as well.

Comment: @Kuba thank you for the comment, I will try. With "named"  arguments I can accomodate any solution (with or without order restriction), I just want the approach to have no  deleterious side effect and improve code readability (at least on the caller side).

Comment: Could use strings for the names in the rule-based version, e.g. `createInverseGamma["Mean"->m_,"Variance"->v_]:=...` Not sure if this will achieve what you want though.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau A priori I do not want to use strings as you cannot use pattern matching anymore. By example it is impossible to distinguish foo["Variance"->_]  versus  foo["Mean"->_]  by example (AFAIK).

Comment: I don't really see how this is different from just making `Mean` and `Variance` options of the function, to be honest.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit The motivation (for me) is to disambiguate things like NormalDistribution[μ,σ] versus NormalDistribution[μ,σ^2]  or GammaDistribution[shape,scale] versus GammaDistribution[shape,rate]. These choices of parametrizations are language dependent (C++ != R != MMA != Julia) and bug prone (IMHO)

Comment: @SjoerdSmit in the same time I think it would be a "misuse"  of options to use them to define (μ,σ) for a Gaussian distribution.

Comment: @sjoerdsmit you can't pattern match option vales and you need to use long OptionValue syntax.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was recently inspired by [ES6 object desctructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) and made something that fits your needs.

It is part of https://github.com/kubaPod/Meh and I consider it beta but I don't care about proper prerelease since I have zero feedback anyway :)

```
(* ResourceFunction["GitHubInstall"]["kubapod", "meh"] *)

<< Meh`

ClearAll[foo]
foo//es6Decorate
foo[<|
         a_,
         b_Integer,
  "F" -> f_,
         g_:10,
  "J" -> j_:1
|>
]:={a,b,f,g,j}
```

```
foo@<|"b"->2,"a"->1,"F"->3|>
foo@<|"b"->2,"a"->1,"F"->3,"g"->100|>
foo@<|"b"->2.2,"a"->1,"F"->3|>
```

> {1, 2, 3, 10, 1}

> {1, 2, 3, 100, 1}

> foo[<|"b" -> 2.2, "a" -> 1, "F" -> 3|>]

which seems to support what you need because you can do:

```
createInverseGamma // es6Decorate

createInverseGamma[<|"Mean" -> m_, "Variance" -> v_|>] := With[
  {a = (m^2 + 2 v)/v, b = m (m^2 + v)/v}
, InverseGammaDistribution[a, b]
];

createInverseGamma[<|"Mean" -> m_, "StandardDeviation" -> std_|>] := 
  createInverseGamma[<|"Mean" -> m, "Variance" -> std^2|>];

dist = createInverseGamma[<|"Mean" -> 1, "StandardDeviation" -> 2|>]

Mean[dist]             (*1*)
Variance[dist]         (*4*)
```

So yes, not exactly the same syntax but this answer is a side effect.

Comment: Thank you @Kuba, that looks very interesting. I will have a look.