# Make a function work by the keyword instead of argument position while evaluating

Tags: functions, arguments, default

I have a simple function which has default values.

```
foo[a_: 1, b_: 2, c_: 3] := a + b + c
```

To evaluate it, I need to provide the arguments in the same positional order in which the function was constructed. For instance, `f[1, 2, 3]` or `f[a = 1, b = 2, c = 3]` or `f[a = 1, b = 2]` will be equal to 6.

However, in some situations you may want to change the value of `a`  and `c`, but use the default value for `b`. You then must type the default value, and remember the argument positions, which becomes tedious if there are many arguments.

Is there a way to only provide function the modified arguments and evaluate it like say `f[a = 1, c = 5]` (make it show 8 instead of 9) such that it fills in the remaining default positions itself?

My idea was to create a keyword list and position match the argument string keys and use them as inputs. But, it also has a lot of problems: for instance, default values should be included and at times replaced in the keyword list.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [241295](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/241295/5478)?

Comment: Yes, @kuba it looks elegant. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is possible to do with `Options`:

```
ClearAll[foo] ;
Options[foo] = {"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3} ;
foo[opts:OptionsPattern[]] := OptionValue["a"] + OptionValue["b"] + OptionValue["c"] ;

foo[]
foo["a" -> 4, "c" -> 5]
```

Comment: Thank you, I am looking to update it for my problem.

Answer (score 4):

You could use associations as follows:

```
f[in_:<||>]:=With[{m=Merge[{in,<|a->1,b->2,c->3|>},First]},
   m[a]+m[b]+m[c]
];
```

Examples:

```
f[]
(* 6 *)

f[<|a->4,c->5|>]
(* 11 *)
```